# Javascript isn't working for click on hamburger to open and close the hamburger

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width, user.scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <title>Nature Tours | Home</title>
        <!--Ion Icons-->

        <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Google Fonts-->

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Our own stylesheet-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-brand">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-icons open">
                        <i class="icon ion-md-menu"></i>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav-list">
                            <div class="menu-icons close">
                                    <i class="icon ion-md-close"></i>
                                </div>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Destinations</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Booking</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                                </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header> 
        <section class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-message">
                    <h3>The great outdoor</h3>
                    <h1>Adventure</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta ipsa sequi, nam amet dolores quasi repudiandae quam reprehenderit doloremque at corrupti possimus, consequatur officia blanditiis qui maxime eaque similique! Quaerat!
                    </p>
                    <div class="cta">
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Book now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

That is my html and i think there are no spelling mistakes

```
/*Global Style*/
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html{
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

section{
    padding: 5rem 0;
}

body{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

/*Header*/

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 1;*/
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 98rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2)
}

.nav-brand{
    width: 2rem;
}

.menu-icons i{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: #fafafa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close i{
    color: #eb648c;
}

.nav-list{
    width: 25rem;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #d7d4ed;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -26rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: all 650ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-list.active{
    right: 0;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-item{
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.nav-link{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

That is my css and, again, I think there is nothing wrong with it

```
//function expression to select elements
const selectElement = (s) => document.querySelector(s);



//open the menu on click
selectElement('.open').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('.nav-list').classList.add('active');
});

//close the menu on click


selectElement('.close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('.nav-list').classList.remove('active');
});
```

Lastly that is my javascript and I think something must be wrong on this one. What I was trying to do is to add a class when you clicked on the hamburger.  Then when you clicked on the X to close it would remove that class (active). Now the problem is, that I don't know why it isn't working. Everything seems to be pointing to the right direction, and I just cant find the error here, especially because I've been following a tutorial and everything works perfectly for him so I don't know why mine doesn't
the tutorial was made back in august 18 2019 so it isn't old by any means, if you can find the error I would appreciate it SOO much.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me -- are you sure that you script is being referenced in the right location? (script called script.js in a folder called js)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console for you web browser for any errors?  That's always a good place to start debugging javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works my friend. Check your imports. 
I placed these in root with the index.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much, i didn't realise, I thought about everything but that lmao, thanks it works now.